# Why does the ethanol-water mixture not burn during fractional distillation?

Tags: boiling-point, distillation

Ethanol-water solution has a flash point lower than ethanol's boiling point in [almost all cases](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol#Chemistry). So how is the fractional distillation of the solution possible? Why doesn't the solution ignite? Is it because there is no oxygen for the flames to be sustained?

Comment: The flash point is the temperature where an external ignition source can set the vapour alight, not the temperature where the vapour spontaneously ignites. If you do a distillation using a naked flame and the vapour leaks, this is a problem. But you should never use naked flames to distill flammable liquids. And you won't have a problem is the vessel doesn't leak.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol), ethanol flash point is $\pu{55 ^\circ F} = \pu{12 ^\circ C}$. Auto-ignition temperature is $\pu{793 ^\circ F} = \pu{423 ^\circ C}$.
It means that ethanol vapor cannot be put on fire with a match at a temperature under $\pu{12 ^\circ C}$. But its vapor will not spontaneously ignite at temperature lower than $\pu{423 ^\circ C}$.